# Docker Error when proxy is set : proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am facing one weird issue with docker. We have a corporate proxy and using docker on Windows server 2016.

I am trying to pull docker image from dockerhub.

Started facing this issue recently. It was working fine earlier.

**Steps**

1) Set HTTP and HTTPS Proxy

2) Executed docker pull hello-world:nanoserver

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host
```

[image]

Any idea whats going wrong here. I have couple of other machines having same setting and works fine.

**Update 1:** **06/03/2019**

I did some trial and error and found that docker version is the culprit here.

I installed docker 17.06.2-ee-17, 17.06.2-ee-16 and tried pulling image. It worked fine.

[image]

So now question is what is wrong with latest 3 versions of docker ee for windows. i.e 17.06.2-ee-18,17.06.2-ee-19,17.06.2-ee-20 which is giving me this error.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the proxy settings. Is there any authentication required to connect to the proxy ?

Comment: Yes I am providing the authentication as well while setting proxy variable. i.e http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport format

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same issues.

It appears to work in the newer versions when we used the fully qualified version of our proxy server.

i.e. `http://proxy-server.my-domain.net:8080` instead of `http://proxy-server:8080`

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, My answer is for ***Linux*** (**"Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:Proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp:lookup proxy.example.com:no such host"**) 
Firsty check docker version with this command (***$docker -v*** ) 
Output: **Docker version 19.03.10, build 9424aeaee9** (**Can be any version**)

Check Can you ping to google (***$ping google.com*** ) 
If it work, dont need to fix the file (**/etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf**)

***$sudo snap install docker***

Then check PATH environment variable
***$echo $PATH*** 
**/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin** ( Output must be like this)

The output doesn't include /snap/bin path. You can define with below command 
***$export -n PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin*** 
***$echo $PATH*** ( check with this command )

Now login to docker hub 
***$docker login***

When login succeeded,can pull any images from docker hub 
***$docker pull hello-world***